# GWT How to only refresh page frame without refreshing the whole page

Tags: java, html, gwt

I need to refresh GWT page all content inside parent panel called dockPanel in my class to clean cache after user click Submit button. What I am doing now is refresh the whole page using

```
Window.Location.reload();
```

It may give user bad experience, because the whole page will be refreshed. Is there any way only to refresh all things in parent panel to give user better experience? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "clean cache"?

Comment: Just to clean up something that may stored in cache. Have any idea how to refresh only the GWT frame? Thanks!

Comment: What "cache"? Refreshing a page does nothing to a browser cache.

Comment: while click on submit but you can create new object of iframe it will help to refresh. every time it will load new iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please give me some sample code of doing your way?